# Why required form field has #required=FALSE on theme level?

Tags: 7, theming, forms

I have a form with managed file field. Form has single field. I have declared this field as required and indeed after submit without file I have an error: Field is required.

I wanted to add HTML5 validation to this field, but in my custom theme_file implementation $variables array has `#required => FALSE` for this field...

I have even red asterisk above this input field so I truly don't know what is wrong..

My custom theme_file:

```
function custom_file($variables) {
    if (! _custom_isMyTheme()) {
        return theme_file($variables);
    }

    $tpl = <<<HTML
    <div class="inputFile" style="width:390px; height:36px;">
        <div class="inputFileContainer">
            <div class="inputFileField"></div>
            <div class="inputFileButton">%s</div>
        </div>
        %s
    </div>
HTML;
    dpm($variables);//devel shows #required property as FALSE
    return sprintf($tpl, t('Select'), theme_file($variables));
}
```

Comment: I see it too – adding a required managed file field has `#required => TRUE` in `theme_field_widget()`, and then `drupal_render_children()` in the render chain, and then in `drupal_render()` it suddenly becomes `FALSE` and remains thusly in your `theme_file()` implementation. My initial guess is that the `input type="file"` isn't required but the hidden input *is*. I'll look a bit deeper into form.inc locally and see if I have more ideas...

Comment: Agh my eyes! What are you doing with that HEREDOC? Please, consider using a theme hook! see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/83855/487

Comment: @barraponto if he's overriding `theme_file`, why would he need to declare a new theme function?

Comment: Yeah, he can use template file with hook_theme_alter. But I don't recall seeing any HEREDOC template in a theme funcion...

Comment: I am calling stadard theme_file function too, so using heredoc has totally no meaning in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, the `hidden` input field that stores the file ID (fid) is what is required, but the displayed file upload element isn't. The actual "displayed" element is added to that form element in `file_managed_file_process()` in `file.module`. Specifically, check out line 440 of that file:

```
  // The file upload field itself.
  $element['upload'] = array(
    '#name' => 'files[' . implode('_', $element['#parents']) . ']',
    '#type' => 'file',
    '#title' => t('Choose a file'),
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    '#size' => $element['#size'],
    '#theme_wrappers' => array(),
    '#weight' => -10,
  );
```

This has no `#required` property, and so therefore defaults to `FALSE`. If you `dpm()` your element earlier in the process (before it's expanded to include more hidden elements and attach the necessary javascript and CSS to be a full-fledged "managed file" element) you'll see your `#required => TRUE`.

I would add an additional function to the `#process` property of your form element, which will run after `file_managed_file_process()`. In it, you can check if the original element had `#required => TRUE` and then also set that on the `$element['upload']` item. I haven't tried it, but I think that would get you what you want.

**Edit:** It would be wiser to do this in `#after_build` and not just append to `#process`. Here's an example:

```
<?php

function my_form_builder($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['file'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#title' => 'Upload a File',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#after_build' => array('my_file_element_after_build')
  );

  return $form;
}

function my_file_element_after_build($element, &$form_state) {
  // Set the 'file' element to have the same #required property as its original form element.
  $element['upload']['#required'] = $element['#required'];
  return $element;
}

?>
```

Comment: Could you provide working example, what am I trying isn't working

Comment: Example form with file input that I am using is here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84301/why-submit-button-is-losing-disabled-attribute-after-deletion-of-uploaded-file

Comment: If you need to alter a form array *after* the `#process` phase, use the `#after_build` callbacks. See http://www.appnovation.com/drupal_tip_using_formafter_build

Comment: barraponto is right, it should be done in an `#after_build` function. I'll edit my answer.